# Is it possible to chain commands via FormFlow?

Tags: botframework

**Dialog** can do almost everything according to the bot framework documentation, but it will take a lot more time to investigate than **FormFlow**. I failed to find a place that have lots of samples of bot framework yet. At the moment, before I spend a lot of time to try dialog, anyone know if it's possible to chain commands using **FormFlow**.

The work I am trying to do is to code a chain of commands:

1. query records
2. select a record from the results
3. actions/operations on the record
4. etc...

Really appreciate if anyone familiar with **Bot Framework** can help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `IDialogStack.Call` method in your FormFlow handlers to call another dialog and push it on the stack.

Then use the `IDialogStack.Done` method to pop it off the stack.  [Both described here.](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/de/db4/interface_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_dialogs_1_1_internals_1_1_i_dialog_stack.html)

Comment: After write some code to verify this, it's good way to get that done. Thanks for your insight & help.